# JS Trigger submit event while preventing default

Tags: javascript, form-submit, event-listener

I have a from I added a event listener to for the submit event like this:

```
form.addEventListener('submit',function(event){
event.preventDefault();
/*some few hundred more lines*/
},false);
```

My issue is when I use this bit of js later on:
`from.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));`
The function is processed, but the page is reloaded because `preventDefault()` had no effect, how can a dispatch a event and not trigger the default?

Comment: First, to manually submit, you only need to write: `from.submit()`. Second, to avoid the `preventDefault()` that is hard wired, you'll need to wrap that into a conditional and then test for some condition that determines if you want to submit or not.

Comment: The real question becomes, why do you have a submit event handler that always cancels the event?

Comment: EVERYTHING is handled by the following javascript, it fetches data from the server and inserts data into the existing page

Comment: `from` or `form`?

Comment: fixed that, it was meant as a example variable, it is actually referenced using the element name from the document object

Answer (score 0):

1) you also need e.stopPropogation(), and even though it's redundant these days, to cope with old IE, it's good form to return 0 at the end

2) practically speaking, just stop making the button a submit button.  submit explicitly means "send to the other end."  just handle the button's onclick instead.

Comment: On point #2 you can hit enter on a input field to submit a from; on point #1 i am not supporting IE8 and below

Comment: It really sounds like you shouldn't be using a form, or shouldn't be setting a target/method on the form, instead of trying to stop in process

However I gave you the answer you're asking for in 1.

Comment: Target is # also neither return false/0 or stopPropogation had any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `action` on the form to `javascript:void(0);` instead of `#` worked.